# Excel Column Graph with Varying Witdths

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am looking for a Microsoft add-in or application in which I can create column graphs with varying widths.

Id' like something similar to the ones used on [informine.com](http://www.infomine.com/graphics/suppliers/WorldMineCostDataExchange/graph.gif)
or [alterenergystocks.com](http://www.altenergystocks.com/assets/3.22.11%20Grid%20Markets.png)

Any ideas or assistance?

Comment: You can do it in excel - try looking at these webpages [1](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/variable-width-column-charts/) [2](http://www.andypope.info/charts/colwidth2.htm) [3](http://www.thepoorhouse.org.uk/oneclick_variable_width_column_charts_in_excel) If you supply us with some sample data in the format you're using, we may be able to provide some step-by-step instructions

Comment: This should be an answer really, peltiertech was definitely my first thought for this.

Comment: Thank you both. <http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/variable-width-column-charts/> did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in excel - try looking at [this](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/variable-width-column-charts/) webpage.